# Add/update SEO metakeywords programmatically of woocommerce product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, seo, yoast

Could you tell me please, what is the best way to add/update SEO metakeywords programmatically?

i looked it up and found on this article how to update meta title and meta desc : https://ehikioya.com/how-to-update-yoast-seo-fields-programmatically/

when i tried to update the meta key words with the same code it wont work.

```
$updated_title = update_post_meta($post_id, ‘_yoast_wpseo_title’, $metatitle); //working
$updated_desc = update_post_meta($post_id, ‘_yoast_wpseo_metadesc’, $metadesc); //working
$updated_kw = update_post_meta($post_id, ‘_yoast_wpseo_metakeywords’, $metakeywords); // not working
```

I’m writing a plugin for import products and categories in WooCommerce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that Yoast SEO removed metakeywords. Searching the plugin code only title and metadesc still exist. Here is an article from Yoast explaining it
[Meta keywords: why we don't use them](https://yoast.com/meta-keywords/)

You may instead need to try using their Focus keyword meta ie _yoast_wpseo_focuskw

Answer (score 2):

after few hours i found the right key, if anyone ever come across this issue here is the soultion.

using the key : "_yoast_wpseo_focuskw"

```
$updated_kw = update_post_meta($product_id, '_yoast_wpseo_focuskw', $metakeywords);
```